# C# JSON Derialization - single class for any property name

Tags: c#, json

I have the following classes that the JSON (which will follow) can deserialize into:

```
public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("entries")]
    public NestedStatEntries Entries { get; set; }
}

public partial class NestedStatEntries
{
    [JsonProperty("activeMemberCnt")]
    public LongValue ActiveMemberCnt { get; set; }
}

public class LongValue
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public long Value { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    "entries": {
        "activeMemberCnt": {
            "value": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use that same `LongValue` wrapper class for similar JSON responses that would have just a single value that's an integer as below, put perhaps, instead of "value", the key would be something like "metric".

**Other JSON:**

```
{
    "entries": {
        "activeMemberCnt": {
            "metric": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to **remove** the `[JsonProperty("value")]` from `LongValue`, and dynamically set it from outside this class, so that I can re-use that same object for responses that have the same value type, but a key, such as the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change *NestedStatEntries* declaration as

```
public partial class NestedStatEntries
{
    [JsonProperty("activeMemberCnt")]
    public Dictionary<string,long> ActiveMemberCnt { get; set; }
}
```

*Similar Dictionary trick as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47189558/c-sharp-jsonconverter-custom-serialization)*